# How to count each distinct values in one column in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a table like the following:
[image: overview of the table]

Now I want to count for each distinct "wfc" how many different "wfv" are there. And make a new column containing the count value. So in the result the table should look like the following:

```
> wfc           Count 
 Arzt_DOKU       1 
 BERUFGRP        6 
 BERUFGRP2       6
```

Comment: What have you tried? Should be enough to `GROUP BY` wfc and count `DISTINCT` wfv

Comment: I think you need to GROUP BY with both columns since you are required to see each distinct "wfc" how many different "wfv" are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select wfc, count(*)
from MyTable
group by wfc
```

if you have duplicates in wfv you can also run to count each of them just once

```
select wfc, count(distinct wfv)
from MyTable
group by wfc
```